# How to forward request from one NGINX to another but keeping the domain of the first NGINX

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting

I have a sub-domain (foo.domain.com) that is maintained by my organization and in which I don't have control.
The organization configured that domain to point to a Route 53 service and from there I created a policy that sends the request to an ALB which then finally sends it to an EC2 running NGINX.

NGINX will be responsible for URL rewrites to many other services I have running in different EC2 instances.

What I want is, for example:

1. request is sent to foo.domain.com/service1
2. goes to Route53 then to an ALB and then to the EC2 running NGINX
3. in NGIX, I have the following config

...

```
location = /service1/
{
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass https://public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance$request_uri;
}
```

4. This request goes to the EC2 instance running service1, which is another NGINX proxy running a node.js application (npm build kinda thing)

The NGINX service1 conf file is:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        server_name public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance;
        root   /app; #this is where the static files are hosted

        location ~* \.html?$ {
            expires -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate";
        }

        location / {
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # kill cache
            # expires -1;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
```

If I hit the NGINX URL of service1, it works just fine, but the problem is when I call the NGINX proxy from step 3.

When I hit the URL foo.domain.com/service1 on the browser, I see this:

[image]

Basically, it says that foo.domain.com/js/chunk....js can't be found. This is correct since this file is being served in the EC2 that is running that node.js application (that is, it can be found at `http://public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance/js/chunk....js`)

What is the configuration that I am missing in order to be able to keep the domain foo.domain.com/service1 for my users at all times and never to see the `public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance`

Thank you

**EDIT 1**
The issue reported here seems to be exactly like mine: https://serverfault.com/questions/805836/reverse-proxy-application-and-its-static-files-with-nginx

I followed the suggestion there and as well as @anemyte suggestion but it is not working.
It seems like Proxy1 is trying to serve the static files that are hosted in Proxy2 as you can see here:

```
proxy    | 2021/01/04 10:16:22 [error] 29#29: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/app.53272292.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/app.53272292.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy    | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2021:10:16:22 +0000] "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy    | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2021:10:16:22 +0000] "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy    | 2021/01/04 10:16:22 [error] 29#29: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/app.0988b263.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy    | 2021/01/04 10:16:22 [error] 29#29: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy    | 2021/01/04 10:16:23 [error] 29#29: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy    | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2021:10:16:23 +0000] "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy    | 2021/01/04 10:16:23 [error] 29#29: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/app.53272292.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/app.53272292.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy    | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2021:10:16:23 +0000] "GET /js/app.53272292.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
```

My proxy 1 conf file looks like this now:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    log_format  main   '( $proxy_host $upstream_addr ) $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    rewrite_log on;
    access_log         /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
         server {
            listen 80;
            server_name apacbsa.com;
            
 
            location /auspost/ {
                # proxy_redirect              off;
                # proxy_read_timeout          1m;
                # proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
                proxy_set_header            Host $host;
                proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
                proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                # proxy_buffering off;
                #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_pass https://192.168.1.113/;
                
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT2**

Still no luck. This is what I am seeing in NGINX1 logs:

```
proxy | ( 192.168.1.113 192.168.1.113:443 ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:37 +0000] "GET /auspost/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:37 +0000] "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:37 [error] 21#21: *9 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:37 +0000] "GET /js/app.54337cb4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:37 +0000] "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:37 [error] 21#21: *12 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/app.54337cb4.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/app.54337cb4.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:37 [error] 21#21: *11 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/app.0988b263.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:37 [error] 21#21: *13 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:37 +0000] "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:38 +0000] "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:38 +0000] "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:38 [error] 21#21: *12 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/app.0988b263.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/app.0988b263.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:38 [error] 21#21: *11 open() "/etc/nginx/html/css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /css/chunk-vendors.e78a06e5.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:39 +0000] "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:39 [error] 21#21: *13 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | 2021/01/05 00:00:39 [error] 21#21: *11 open() "/etc/nginx/html/js/app.54337cb4.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.19.0.1, server: apacbsa.com, request: "GET /js/app.54337cb4.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/auspost/"
proxy | ( - - ) 172.19.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:00:00:39 +0000] "GET /js/app.54337cb4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "http://localhost/auspost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "-"
```

And this is what I see in the NGINX2 (serving static files) logs (just 1 line):

```
frontend | 172.21.0.1 - - [05/Jan/2021:11:04:17 +1100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0" "172.19.0.1"
```

This is the full nginx conf file for NGINX2:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main   '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log         /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile           on;

    keepalive_timeout 10m;
    proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
    proxy_send_timeout  600s;
    proxy_read_timeout  600s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    resolver_timeout 600s;

    # for DDOS protection - 3 requests per second
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=3r/s;
    # limiting the number of connections one client can make
    limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name apacbsa.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        include snippets/self-signed.conf;
        server_name apacbsa.com;
        root   /app;

        location ~* \.html?$ {
            expires -1;
            add_header Pragma "no-cache";
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store, must-revalidate";
        }

        location /auspost/ {
            add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';";
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            index  index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # kill cache
            # expires -1;
        }

        location /api {
                # limiting the number of api calls
                limit_req zone=one burst=2 nodelay;
                # only one connection per client to the api
                limit_conn addr 1;

                proxy_pass          https://backend:5001/api;
                proxy_redirect              off;
                proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is running in docker containers, but that shouldn't be the problem I don't think.

So I issue the request from my browser in my Mac laptop and in that laptop I am running the NGINX1 proxy. That then forwards to my Windows machine running NGINX2 static files.

Comment: Hi. I have a couple of questions: 1) What is the base path for the static files that your application is looking for ? is it domain.com/service1/js/....  or domain.com/js/....?

Comment: 2) The logs you shared. Can you clearly label which Nginx they belong to? If possible, can I see logs for both Nginx ?

Comment: Hi @ManishDash - the logs I shared relate to NGINX1, the one that forwards to the NGINX2 serving the static content. I will update my post to include the logs from NGINX2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a location like that:

```
location = /service1/
```

It means that you want exact URL match. So it will only work for `foo.domain.com/service1/` while `foo.domain.com/service1/something` won't match this location. Looking at the URL of your request (`/js/chunk`) this isn't what you want, so remove `=` from the location:

```
location /service1/
```

Next is the `server_name`. Your first proxy passes `Host` header which NGINX uses to determine which vhost configuration to use. The `Host` header value should be `foo.domain.com` but your `server_name` on the second NGINX is `public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance`. It doesn't matter if the vhost is a default one but I don't see that in your configuration.

You can add `foo.domain.com` after `public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance` or just replace one with the other. What's best in this case you should decide yourself and if you wish to learn more about server names I recommend you reading these great articles: [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

**UPD:** About missing static files.

You need to change base URL or base path of your `service1` application from `/` to `/service1/`. This is not related to NGINX, unless your application is made of just static files.

Why did that happen? Well you've told `first NGINX` that you want all requests with URL starting with `/service1/` to be forwarded to `service1`. When a client hits `service1`, the page refers some static, `/js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js` for example. Client's browser makes an additional request to the `first NGINX` asking to provide `/js/chunk-vendors.7b27d7ff.js`. Since the URL does not begin with `/service1/` NGINX does not forward the request to `/service1/` and it uses another piece of config for this request (`/` most likely).

If you change all absolute URLs at `service1` to begin with `/service1/` the problem should go. A dangerous alternative to that would be **removing** first slash from absolute links. This way URLs will be relative to **current** location and not website root. Think twice before going second option.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestions but it is unfortunately not working.
It seems like Proxy1 is trying to serve all static content from Proxy2 as http://proxy1/js/chunk...)
This person had the same issue https://serverfault.com/questions/805836/reverse-proxy-application-and-its-static-files-with-nginx and was able to fix with location /service1/ as you suggested, but I am not sure why it is not working for me.

Comment: I was not able to fit explanation into comment so I've added it to the end of my answer. @FelipeCaldas

Comment: I see what you mean @anemyte. My NGINX2 which serves the static content indeed only has "location / {". I will test this later today and revert back. Thank you.

Comment: I added more info to my post under EDIT2, thanks for your support.

Comment: You got it wrong, @FelipeCaldas . Your static requests will never reach `second` NGINX because their URLs do not begin with `/service1/`. `first` NGINX does not treat them as belonging to `service1` as they do not match the pattern for `service1`. Instead, they match some other pattern (probably `/`) but it ends up with 404 because, you know, there are no such files.
You need to add `/service1` to the beginning of all URLs in  service1, this option is usually called `base URL`.

Comment: Sorry @anemyte, I have given you the wrong information. The path is indeed `/auspost` so I am calling `http://localhost/austpost/` which reaches NGINX1 and then reaches NGINX2, but then the static files are not served. In NGINX2 I do have `location /auspost/` so shouldn't all this be matching now? Thank you

Comment: @FelipeCaldas As you said, you are calling `/auspost/` and it works. The problem is - your static files path begins with `/js/` or `/css/`, not `/auspost/`. Since it is not `/auspost/` it does not go to second NGINX (the matching rule do not apply) and to fix that you need that you links for static are prefixed with `/auspost/`. For example: `/auspost/js/something.js`, `/auspost/css/main.css` and so on.

Comment: so I guess the problem is in the "routes" of my Node.js application where my application starts at `/` and not `/auspost/`. Something I will have to test. I will get back to you soon. Thanks again

Comment: @FelipeCaldas Yes, exactly. This is often called 'base path' or 'base URL'.

Comment: although I have not been able yet to crack this one down, I feel like your assistance here definitely took me closer to the root of the issue. I am accepting your post. I am now trying to fix this from a Node.js configuration perspective and when I fix it I will post the final solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have done some testing lately and here's what I found out:

In your nginx proxy config, remove the line:

> proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

Which will result in your final configuration nginx file to be:

```
location = /
{
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_pass https://public_ip_of_service1_ec2_instance;
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, thank you for your message. I updated my question with further information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could configure something like this in the first nginx server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

    server_name domain1;

    if ($request_method ~* OPTIONS|GET|HEAD) {
        return 301 https://domain2$request_uri;
    }

    location ~* api {
        proxy_pass https://domain2$request_uri;
    }
}
```